# Python C-API: segmentation fault on PyDict_GetItem, possible reference problem?

Tags: python, c++, python-c-api

I have a reference in C to a Python list of dictionaries. I am writing a function to calculate the dot product between two members of the list:

```
PyObject *handle; // reference to a list of dictionaries
virtual float dot_product () (unsigned i, unsigned j) const {
    // dot product of handle[i] and handle[j]
    PyObject *a = (PyObject*)PyList_GetItem(handle, (Py_ssize_t)i);
    PyObject *b = (PyObject*)PyList_GetItem(handle, (Py_ssize_t)j);
    PyObject *key, *a_value;
    Py_ssize_t pos = 0;
    double dot_product = 0;
    while (PyDict_Next(a, &pos, &key, &a_value)) {
        PyObject* b_value = PyDict_GetItem(b, key);
        if (b_value != NULL){
            dot_product += PyFloat_AsDouble(a_value) * PyFloat_AsDouble(b_value);
        }
    }
    return dot_product;
}
```

This results in a segmentation fault. Using gdb to debug, it appears that the segmentation fault is being caused by PyDict_GetItem(b, key). This makes me suspect there's something wrong with my reference counts.

After reading the documentation on [Reference Counts](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/extending.html#ownership-rules), it seems that all of the references in the above code are borrowed, so I assumed there was no need to use Py_INCREF or Py_DECREF...but I could easily be wrong.  Is there a place in the above code that I need to use Py_INCREF or Py_DECREF?

Edit: I should note that I have already done checks to make sure a and b are not null, and also checks to ensure i and j do not exceed the size of the list. I removed these checks from the code in my question to keep it simpler. –

Comment: Are there any threads, at all, involved in this program? Are the keys of the `dict`s Python built-ins, or some custom class? By not holding owned references, it's possible the `__hash__` or `__eq__` methods of your keys either directly change the `list`s or `dict`s you're working with, or invoke Python code that allows for GIL handoff, allowing some other thread to begin running and do the same thing.

Comment: Beyond that, you aren't checking return values; `a` and `b` could easily be `NULL` if `j` is greater than the length of the `list` stored in `handle`, and if you don't check the return values, you'll end up trying to deference null pointers. `PyDict_GetItem` suppresses the exception for a missing key, but it doesn't try to guard against a `NULL` value for the `dict` itself.

Comment: The keys of the dict are integers, so Python built-ins. You might be onto something with threads: the encompassing program is multi-threaded, and so dot_product may be called simultaneously. I will try a single-threaded version and see if that fixes things.

Comment: It also depends on whether your `dot_product()` call is wrapped directly under a Python call or not. Python function calls increment the ref count implicitly for you, but if you are actively calling your dot_product from C++ you need to do that by yourself.

Comment: Are you using Python 3.10 or later? In earlier versions, `PyDict_GetItem` does not check for the GIL, which can cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

Check your return values. Both `a` and `b` can be `NULL` if `i` and `j` respectively exceed the length of the `list` referenced by `handle`. `PyDict_GetItem` *assumes* the `dict` passed is not a `NULL` pointer, dereferencing it without confirming that assumption, which would cause an immediate segfault.

You main problem is determining how to report an error. A C++ exception would work for C++, but Python won't understand it unless you catch it and convert it to a Python level exception. In any event, until you figure that out, returns `NaN` to indicate failure:

```
#include <cmath>

PyObject *handle; // reference to a list of dictionaries
virtual float dot_product () (unsigned i, unsigned j) const {
    // dot product of handle[i] and handle[j]
    PyObject *key, *a_value;
    Py_ssize_t pos = 0;
    double dot_product = 0;

    // Check both indices are valid
    PyObject *a = (PyObject*)PyList_GetItem(handle, (Py_ssize_t)i);
    if (!a) return NAN;

    PyObject *b = (PyObject*)PyList_GetItem(handle, (Py_ssize_t)j);
    if (!b) return NAN;

    // Test if you actually got dicts
    if (!PyDict_Check(a) || !PyDict_Check(b)) return NAN;

    while (PyDict_Next(a, &pos, &key, &a_value)) {
        PyObject* b_value = PyDict_GetItem(b, key);
        if (b_value != NULL){
            // Check that both values are really Python floats and extract C double
            double a_val = PyFloat_AsDouble(a_value);
            if (a_val == -1.0 && PyErr_Occurred()) return NAN;

            double b_val = PyFloat_AsDouble(b_value);
            if (b_val == -1.0 && PyErr_Occurred()) return NAN;

            dot_product += a_val * b_val;
        }
    }
    return dot_product;
}
```

Comment: I should have said this in my question, but I've already done null checking and making sure i and j do not exceed the size of the list. I removed the checking from the code in my question to keep it simpler.